# Bootstrap 2 flashing horizontal lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I have noticed that after one of the lastest updates of chrome, the flash behavior of white horizontal lines appeared when moving mouse over button. I wasn't able to find any information regarding this matter and I wonder if there is any fix or workaround for this ugly behavior.

It's easy to observe this behavior on blue button: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: I'm with Firefox, can't show it... But I see the flash in Chromium... So it could maybe be a browser issue... :-/